# BigRquery - RUN_QUERY_JOB

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery

I've installed "bigrquery" like this:

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/bigrquery")
library(bigrquery)
```

And i get this error, when trying to extract data:

```
Error: Access Denied: Job triple-xxx-xxx:job_zu6P-qSxxx7DBVICij6_QyDv0: RUN_QUERY_JOB
```

I've looked here and on the web and everyone says that you just need 2 things to extrac data from Google BigQuery:

1.-Have a Project for it (BigQuery Enabled):

2.-Put a billing address for BigQuery.

I've done that, but still got the problem.

**IMPORTAT: 
For other packages that interact with Google products (Google Analytics), e.g RGA; you need to create a Client ID (OAUTH), do i need to to this with "bigrquery"???**

Someone can update the method to get the data?

Ps. I can get the data in the broswer (with the Web Interface provided by Google). But not in R from "bigrquery" - I'm using the version hosted on CRAN.

Ps2. I don't want that the "authentications" to be stored in the cache, is there a way to make "bigrquery" to ask for authentication everytime it tries to connect to BigQuery?

I found this issue on this post, but with the solution out-of-date:

[Google App Engine authorization for Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534709/google-app-engine-authorization-for-google-bigquery)

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the user that was running the query was not authorized to run jobs in the project (`triple-xxx-xxx`). You'd need to add the user that is running the query to the project via the developers console (https://console.developers.google.com/project).

To answer some of your other questions:

- You don't need to create a clientid to use bigquery.
- I'm not sure if there is a way to force bigrquery to re-authorize every time. That said, looking at the source code (https://github.com/hadley/bigrquery/blob/master/R/auth.r) you may be able to call set_access_cred with null to clear the authentication.

Comment: i've used "reset_access_cred()", but bigrquery still don't ask for an authentication. Is there a way to remove every thing from bigrquery to star over again? (without uninstalling?).

Comment: Also, in "https://console.developers.google.com/project/triple-xxx-xxx/**permissions**"

I've three emails: 1) my personal email: oma.goxxx@gmail.com. 2) triple-xxxx-xxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com (email with the project id as username). 3) 901433920374-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com (Google API service account). All can edit, my personal email is the owner.... I need to change something?