# bigrquery throwing "Error: Invalid Credentials" when using query_exec()

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I've been using the bigrquery library in r to run queries on my google big query project for the past 6 months. This morning I ran a simple query_exec() command that I've run a number of times over the past few days and I got the simple message "Error: Invalid Credentials".

I haven't been able to find documentation telling me how to fix this. I'm also not sure how to give code that will recreate the error.

The only thing that I can think of that changed is that I signed into a different gmail account.

Steps attempted so far:

1. I logged out of the gmail account and logged back in to the right one.
2. I uninstalled everything about R on my computer and reinstalled it all.

Still no luck.

I'm also realizing that there isn't a ton of information here.
If there's something else I can provide that I haven't thought of I will be happy to answer questions.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4):

After more searching I found a way to clear your access credentials in this question and answer: [BigRquery - RUN_QUERY_JOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726977/bigrquery-run-query-job)

To summarize, if you force the access credentials to be null `set_access_cred(NULL)`, then get new credentials `get_access_cred()`; you can re-authenticate.

Comment: I have done same thing but gives same error. it gives this erroe :          > bigrquery::set_access_cred(NULL)
> igrquery::get_access_cred()                                                                 
<Token>                                  
<oauth_endpoint>                                           
 authorize: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
 access:    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
<oauth_app> google
  key:    465736758727.apps.googleusercontent.com
  secret: <hidden>
<credentials> error
---

Comment: Try running `reset_access_cred()`, then running the script again. I was able to get the same error, but my query is running just fine.

Comment: I got solution. I need to remove .httr-oauth file and than reset_access_cred(). That solved issue

Comment: @DivyangShah Where do you find the .httr-oauth file?

Comment: In working directory at the command line try `ls -a` to show hidden files.

Comment: hi @Praxiteles I can't remind the location right now. but, I think with httr package you can use below command
file.remove('.httr-oauth')